# TypeError: s.replace is not a function

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

**Env:**

- Postgres: 10.2
- Node: 6.11.0
- CLI: 2.4.0
- ORM: 2.1.3

**Model:**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var test = sequelize.define('test', {
        id: DataTypes.UUID,
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        data: DataTypes.JSON,
    }, {
        'createdAt': {
            type: Sequelize.DATE(3),
            defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)'),
        },
        'updatedAt': {
            type: Sequelize.DATE(3),
            defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)'),
        },
        classMethods: {
            associate: function(models) {
                // associations can be defined here
            }
        }
    });
    return test;
}
```

**Migration:**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
    up: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        return queryInterface.addColumn('test', {
            test_col: {
                type: Sequelize.JSONB
            }
        });
    },
    down: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        return queryInterface.removeColumn('test', 'test_col');
    }
};
```

**Error:**

```
TypeError: s.replace is not a function
    at Object.removeTicks (/node_modules/sequelize/lib/utils.js:329:14)
    at Object.addTicks (/node_modules/sequelize/lib/utils.js:325:29)
    at Object.quoteIdentifier (/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query-generator.js:835:22)
    at Object.addColumnQuery (/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query-generator.js:182:19)
    at QueryInterface.module.exports.QueryInterface.addColumn
```

Comment: Probably because `s` is null

Comment: @AlexanderMP but y is `s` is null ? Any idea ?

Comment: If I knew, I wouldn't have written it in a comment :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The syntax used for migration is incorrect. The queryInterface.addcolumn method expects 3 arguments while you are passing only 2. See [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/query-interface.js~QueryInterface.html#instance-method-addColumn).

`public addColumn(table: String, key: String, attribute: Object, options: Object): Promise`

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.addColumn(
          'pages',
          'group',
          Sequelize.JSONB
      );
  },
  down: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.removeColumn('pages', 'group');
  }
};
```

And to anybody getting `s.replace` error it is basically because you are not passing the expected type of argument. So in above case, an object was passed as second parameter to `queryInterface.addColumn` while it was expecting a `String` literal. Read more [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/6530).

Comment: Thank you for the note on `s.replace`. For me, I had a poorly formatted `where:{}` definition on a `Model.findAll` method call.